# Prolog: Convert HTML to prolog onClick=window.location

Tags: html, prolog

I want to convert my site to prolog and I have this code in HTML:

```
<p align="center"><input type="submit"  id="sublog" name="login" value="Log in" />
     <input type="submit" id="subreg" onclick="window.location='http://localhost/CVnator/CVnator/register.php'; return false;" value="Register" /></p>
```

and i am trying to make it in swi-prolog, i did this and it works but i don't know how to set the onClick:

```
    p([align='center'], input([name=login, type=submit, value='Log in'])),
p([align='center'], input([name=login, type=submit, value='Register']))
```

i need to put it to the Register paragraph how do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be working for me:

```
?- phrase(
    html(p([align='center'], 
         input([name=login, type=submit, value='Register', 
                onclick='window.location=''http://localhost/CVnator/CVnator/register.php'';return false;']))), 
    X), 
   print_html(X).

<p align="center">
<input name="login" type="submit" value="Register" 
       onclick="window.location='http://localhost/CVnator/CVnator/register.php';return false;">
```

I suppose the trick is to double-up the single quotes to embed them.